# Custom view - Crash in "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" method

Tags: ios, swift, init

**Code:**

```
class HeaderView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    finishInit()
}

func finishInit() {
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

func setView(withTitle title: String?) {
    titleLabel.backgroundColor  = UIColor.white
    titleLabel.text = title

}
```

**Crash:**

On finishInit() method, while setting label background color

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But same, on setView() method, is not crashing.

Comment: check your Outlet connection in your xib or storyboard

Comment: Outlet is working for setView() method

Comment: Your setView method is called? i think your finishInit() is called first and crash before that

Comment: I tried to call setView method from another view, on which "HeaderView" is added as a subview. I commented finishInit for testing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the `init` methods run and return, the connections of the outlets are not yet made. Therefore the outlets are still `nil` and you are crashing when using it.

You should be able to test this by adding a question mark (?) after the `titleLabel` and thus treating it like an optional again.

`titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`

Then you will not crash but the line will also not do anything of course if the label is still nil.

So you need to call the code that uses the outlets later (which you seem to be doing with `setView`?

You might use `awakeFromNib` where the outlets should be set.

Comment: Yes, awakeFromNib works perfectly fine. I was just curious to know the exact reason for crash. Something like "self.backgoundColor = UIColor,white" is not crashing, only when setting subViews properties crash happens. Your answer is on the mark, Thanks :)